# Angular 6: get reference to Components created with *ngFor inside ng-container tag

Tags: angular, angular6, ngfor, viewchild, ng-container

I'using ng-container to iterate on a list and create components

```
    <ng-container *ngFor="let f of optionsList; let i = index;">

                <!-- component-->
                <app-component  #fieldcmp  *ngIf="isAppComponent(f)" ></app-field>


                <!--another components-->
                <app-anoter-component1 *ngIf="isAnotherComponent1(f)"> </app-anoter-component1>
...
                <app-anoter-componentn *ngIf="isAnotherComponentn(f)"> </app-anoter-componentn>

            </ng-container>
```

I would to list of References components inside ng-container.

I tried  to use 
    @ViewChildren('#fieldcmp')  fieldsList: QueryList; and 
   @ContentChildren('#fieldcmp')  fieldsList: QueryList; 
inside father component but i get no elements if I try to acces in ngafterViewInit

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.fieldsList.forEach((child) => {  /* some logic....*/});
    }
```

Can someone can help me?
Thanks

-----------**Update** -----------------------

after fix with  @ViewChildren('fieldcmp') I have a list of **ElementRef** instead of my AppComponent.
I cast it with and all work

```
this.filedsList 
            .forEach((child) => { atLeastOneRequired = atLeastOneRequired || (<ReusableFieldComponent> child).isRequired();
    });
```

thank you to help

Comment: I think it should be just `@ViewChildren('fieldcmp')` (no `#` sign, that is used only in template)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just remove the `#` sign from your `ViewChildren` selector - that is used only in templates:

```
@ViewChildren('fieldcmp') fieldsList: QueryList;
```

Or you could use component class as a selector:

```
@ViewChildren(HelloComponent) fieldsList: QueryList<HelloComponent>;
```

Working stackblitz here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xeudlp

Comment: after fix with @ViewChildren('fieldcmp') I have a list of ElementRef instead of my AppComponent. How can I cast it or convert in my component type?

Comment: use the other approach to get component instances (with `@ViewChildren(HelloComponent)`)

Comment: with @ViewChildren(HelloComponent) I have lenght = 0. I think that the problem is that the components are inside a <ng-container>. For this one exists @ContentChildren but replacing to ViewChildren I have no references too.

Comment: Well it is working for me, see the stackblitz example I provided. I also changed the container element to `ng-container` and still working as expected.

Comment: I use casting, it's working. thank you for the time spent

Comment: Btw you could just set the type to `QueryList<HelloComponent>` instead of casting (like I did in the other approach).

Answer (score 0):

Try create and empty `directive`, then query your Directive and read the `ElementRef`.

`@ViewChildren(MyDirective, {read: Element Ref}) 
Kids: QueryList<ElementRef>;`

I don't have my computer in front of me but that's the idea.